# how Git do the increment pull?

Tags: git

Machine A has a.git, a 50MB log file.

Mchine B use git clone a.git

My question: if the log file just add one line data at A, how B just pull the diff and merge? Not to pull a 50MB file everytime.

Comment: because the commit log

Answer (score 1):

You do not clone every time you want to update "B" with a change made on "A".

Simply `git pull`, and git will pull the diffs between the two commits.

If you don't understand the way that pull does this, check out this page of the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Answer (score 0):

Once you have run git clone on Machine B, you don't have to do a `git clone` everytime. You should just be able to write `git pull` and it will pull in just the changes that were made.

On Machine A, you can also run:

- `git format-patch -1 <sha>`

or

- `git format-patch -1 HEAD`

To apply it on Machine B then you would use:

```
patch -p1 < file.patch
```

However I think the right way is to use `git pull`